# creating a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web-services

I am trying to create a web service in C# asp.NET. I read some explanations in google but I didn't understand something.

the explanation asked me to create a PRODUCT table with some attributes!!
the explanation is in this link: http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/wsdaljava.aspx

should I follow the same steps and creating PRODUCT table or what to do?
I mean I don't know if he used that table in his project or just created it to build a web service.

Thanks.

Comment: The example is showing a common use for a web service: to answer requests by providing data pulled from a database. It is possible to just write a service that returns data from elsewhere, but if you're having trouble following the example given I think you'll have trouble trying to improvise and deviate from that lesson.

Comment: first of all which web services you are willing to create? you want a SOAP services or RESTful ?

Comment: @MuneebAmjad I don't know what is the difference. What I know is I have to create a web service but I don't know that there is different types:(

Comment: google would help you dude :) @user3287580

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9504642/2613639) will help you. Please read this. :)

Comment: follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15127614/2613639) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What he is giving an example of is exposing the data held in the PRODUCT table via a web service. So depending on what you are creating a web service to expose, you may or may not need something similar. You definitely don't need it to match the PRODUCT table in the example but you are creating a web service to DO something. Depending on what that something is will determine what underlying components you need.